# Unable to get azure sdk logs to console for "Microsoft.Azure.Devices" package

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-sdk-.net

I have created a sample .NET 6 console application and added the below line of code as mentioned in the below Microsoft learn website to enable azure sdk client library logs.

```
using AzureEventSourceListener consoleListener =
                                AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger(System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Verbose);
```

[SDK Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging)

In the sample application I am downloading a blob using BlobClient which is defined in the "Azure.Storage.Blobs" nuget package.
And also I am sending a cloud to device message using ServiceClient which is defined in the "Microsoft.Azure.Devices" nuget package.

For the blob client operation I am able to get the sdk logs in console, but for cloud to device message operation using "ServiceClient" I am not able to get the sdk logs.

[image: SDK logs from blob operation] The sdk logs for the blob operation which is logged in console is attached.

Similar log for service client operation is not logged

Could you please help me in getting the sdk logs in console for "Microsoft.Azure.Devices" library

Here is my code

```
using AzureEventSourceListener consoleListener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger(System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Verbose); 
var x = new BlobClient(new Uri("BLOB URL")).Download(); 
ServiceClient _serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("CONN STRING"); 
string msg = "Hi Qwerty"; 
Message message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)); 
await _serviceClient.SendAsync("DEVICE ID", message);
```

Comment: please share your code in the form of text

Comment: using AzureEventSourceListener consoleListener =
                                    AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger(System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Verbose);

 var x = new BlobClient(new Uri("BLOB URL")).Download();

 ServiceClient _serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("CONN STRING");

 string msg = "Hi Qwerty";
 Message message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg));

 await _serviceClient.SendAsync("DEVICE ID", message);

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Devices is not part of the current Azure SDK generation and does not emit logs that the `AzureEventSourceListener` can intercept.   You would need to create an ETW listener that can capture it's source, as discussed in the IoT sample:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/main/samples/helpers/ColorConsoleLogger

Answer (score 0):

- using the package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging  we can log the  data

Install the below packages

```cs
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

- I am able to get the logs

```cs
 AzureEventSourceListener consoleListener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger(System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Verbose);

 // Set up logger
 var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
     .AddLogging(builder =>
     {
         builder.AddConsole();
     })
     .BuildServiceProvider();

 var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

 try
 {
     // Download a blob
     BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(new Uri("https://samstoragehello.blob.core.windows.net/hellocont/_ViewImports.cshtml?sp"));
     BlobDownloadInfo downloadedContent = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

     // Read the downloaded content
     using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(downloadedContent.Content))
     {
         string downloadedContentString = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

         // Send a message to an IoT device
         ServiceClient _serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("HostName=samiothubtodel1.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=");
         string msg = "Hi Qwerty";
         Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message message = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg));
         await _serviceClient.SendAsync("mywebpi", message);

         // Log information including blob content and IoT message content
         logger.LogInformation("Blob downloaded successfully. Content: {BlobContent}", downloadedContentString);

        
         logger.LogInformation("IoT message sent. Content: {IoTMessageContent}", msg);
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     // Log error
     logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred: {ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
 }
```

**Output:**

[image]

- With `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client` from this reference [MSDOC](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/main/tools/CaptureLogs#azure-iot-sdk-providers)

```cs
   DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, TransportType.Mqtt);

 
   deviceClient.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler((status, reason) =>
   {
       logger.LogInformation($"Connection Status Changed - Status: {status}, Reason: {reason}");
   });

   await deviceClient.OpenAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: The logs which you have highlighted in the attached screenshot are the logs added by you and they are not the azure sdk client library logs.

Comment: The logs at the top in the screenshot are the client library logs  (ETag, x-ms-request etc.), these are logs from the BlobClient (Azure.Storage.Blobs libray) but we don't have the logs from Microsoft.Azure.Devices library

Comment: According [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/how-to-collect-device-logs?pivots=programming-language-csharp) Azure IoT SDK [providers](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/main/tools/CaptureLogs#azure-iot-sdk-providers) only this sdks

Comment: given a sample `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client`

Comment: ```DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, TransportType.Mqtt);   // Set up connection status change handler  deviceClient.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler((status, reason) =>  {      logger.LogInformation($"Connection Status Changed - Status: {status}, Reason: {reason}");  });   await deviceClient.OpenAsync();```